# Chrome API missing methods

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension, google-chrome-storage, missingmethod

I'm developing a browser extension and it was working fine until today.
When I'm opening "Inspect pop-up window" console and type `chrome.storage.local` everything looks as expected:
[pop-up window console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIIKQ.png)

But when I open console in any website and check for `storage` I get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local'):
[browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyS6J.png)

In fact, as the title of this question states, I'm missing most of the API methods from `chrome`:
[available methods of chrome variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRjNT.png)

I'm using the latest Microsoft Edge Version 101.0.1210.32 (Official build) (64-bit).
Tried restarting the browser and computer. Clearing all user data, cookies, everything except passwords. Tried logging out and back in in the browser and re-installing my extension as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you might be confusing `chrome.storage.local` with `Window.localStorage`.

It stores the data of the extensions installed in local machine, so it only works in the extension. So youneed to debug it in the `Inspect popup` of the extensions you mentioned above.